# How to handle Writer, Result, OutputStream in Constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

I have a class which encapsulates a StAX Writer for a special business XML writing. You can push into some domain objects and the logic generates the adequate XML.

I don't want to offer the `XMLStreamWriter` instance for security reasons, so this class is the only responsible to write into this writer. The `XMLStreamWriter` will be instanced in this class. To support nearly all output variations, such as Result, OutputStream and Writer I also provide constructos for these variations.

```
public CustomStreamWriter ([...], Result result) {
      this([...], (Object) result);
}

public CustomStreamWriter ([...], OutputStream outputStream) {
      this([...], (Object) outputStream);
}

public CustomStreamWriter ([...], Writer writer) {
      this([...], (Object) writer);
}

protected CustomStreamWriter ([...], Object outputHandler) {
    // Initialize some final fields and do some stuff with [...]
    XMLOutputFactory factory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();

    if(outputHandler instanceof OutputStream) {
       this.writer = factory.createXMLStreamWriter((OutputStream) outputHandler);
    } else if(outputHandler instanceof Result) {
       this.writer = factory.createXMLStreamWriter((Result) outputHandler);
    } else if(outputHandler instanceof Writer) {
       this.writer = factory.createXMLStreamWriter((Writer) outputHandler);
    }
}
```

When I look at it I think this is very ugly and not a neat way to achieve this. Stackoverflow, do you have any hints for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it this way.

```
public CustomStreamWriter ([...], Writer writer) throws XMLStreamException {
    this([...], XMLOutputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamWriter(writer);
}

protected CustomStreamWriter ([...], XMLStreamWriter outputHandler) {
    this.writer = writer;
}
```

If the constructor throws an exception, the constructor cannot handle it and create a valid object, so throwing an exception is a sensible way to handle this.

Comment: Well, in my last work place they would _make_ me to wrap all errors from `newInstance` or `createXMLStreamWriter` into a custom exception, that's why I deleted my answer. (kinda corporate standard, and not necessary a bad one)  But if there's no such requirement, this should work.

Comment: @Nikita, I did see your solution, but don't see the point of wrapping/disguising exceptions unless you are adding some value (or you have to).

Comment: In fact I go as far as using Thread.currentThread().stop(e) instead of wrapping a checked exception.

Comment: The point is usability. Not to make user to employ 15 catch blocks just because you used 3 different internal libraries which produce 15 different exception types. If you're designing API, that makes sense.

Comment: @Nikita, not sure this would ever happen in reality.  You never need to perform more than two or three different actions to handle exceptions, the rest can be caught by a generic catch Exception.